# What is the best way to redirect network requests?

Tags: http, redirect, networking, network-programming

I've written my own HTTP Server, but given certain criteria, I want to redirect some requests made to my server to another server running on the same machine.  For example, I may want to redirect all requests to "/foo/*" to be handled by an apache server I also have running.  What is the best way to do this?

The only way I can think of doing this is by running apache on a different port, and then making a completely new network request from my server to localhost:1234 (assuming apache is running on port 1234) with the same exact request headers and body, and then take the response and have my server send that back to the client.

That seems like a kind of hacky, roundabout way of accomplishing this though, and I'm sure this is a problem that is tackled by every major website. Is there a certain technology or protocol for doing this that I just haven't heard of?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: Just to be clear, the client should only make one network request for all this, rather than having my server return a 3xx response

Answer (score 0):

HTTP runs over TCP. The Apache server can't just send the required response to a client who hasn't asked for it. The client has asked YOUR HTTP server for the data and so it must be the one to send a response. The client is probably behind a firewall and, as such, the Apache server can't even establish a TCP connection with it (incoming connections are usually blocked).

If your server takes the clients request, forwards it to the Apache server, gets the response from the Apache server and forwards it to the client, it's acting as a proxy server (a middleman). This won't be redirection.

The only sensible way to do this would be to have the client make two network requests.